# Compare a file with a column of another file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv, columns, file-comparison

I have a file `File1` with data as

```
aaa
bbb
```

And another file `File2` with data as:

```
2,aaa,234
w,bbb,589
4,ccc,675
```

I need to compare the `File1` data with column2 data of `File2` and print the matching into a one file and the non-matching into another.

Comment: Do you need just the data from `File1`, or also the extra columns that are only in `File2`? Is the order of lines important?

Comment: What would the correct output be for this example?

Answer (score 4):

```
awk -F '
  !b{a[$0]; next}
  $2 in a {print > "matching.txt"; next}
  {print > "non-matching.txt"}' file1 b=1 file2
```

Or with two passes and assuming the files are sorted on the join key:

```
join -t , -2 2 -o 2.1,2.2,2.3 file1 file2 > matching.txt
join -t , -2 2 -v 2 -o 2.1,2.2,2.3 file1 file2 > non_matching.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner uses `cut` to pick out the right field and `grep` to find matches. Matches and non-matches are appended to the files named `Matching` and `NonMatching`, respectively.

`for x in $(cut -d, -f2 File2); do grep -q "$x" File1 && echo "$x" >> Matching || echo "$x" >> NonMatching; done`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command for matching records -

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{f1[$1]=$0;next}$2  in f1{print $0}' OFS="," file1 file2 > matchedRecords.txt
```